# Make jump-breaks only apply to feeds (not web view) with Blogger

Tags: blogger, feeds

I've just started using Blogger, and as I intend my posts to be fairly long, I would like to use a jump-break so that only the first few paragraphs appear in the RSS feed.

However doing so causes the blog's homepage to also only show the first few paragraphs of the single post I am displaying there, while I want the homepage to show the latest post in full.

It seems that I can only do this if I remove the jump break, but then the RSS feed becomes full-length also.  [Changing the feed length](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/42662?hl=en) to "short" isn't great as it's then a bit too short and cuts off in mid-sentence.

I've had a look at the template HTML and the [available data fields](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en), but it appears there is only one field for a post's body (which is automatically shortened to the pre-jump content), so I can't alter the field the template is using to get around this problem either.

Is there any way to effectively make jump-breaks only apply to the RSS feeds, so the web version always shows the full post?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do what you want just using jump-breaks.

An alternative to to remove the jumpbreaks from your posts, and use Feedburner's Summary-feed service to delivery just the first part of your content.   to do this:

- Set up a feed for your blog in Feedburner.com  (and of course make it
  possible to subscribe to this feed from your blog).
- In the Optimise tab in Feedburner, go to Summary Burner, choose the
  number of characters you show and Activate the service.